# Gitlab Community Edition - fatal unable to access repository, could not resolve host

Tags: git, server, version-control, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I have installed Gitlab and Jenkins on my own server and is publicly available. But when I `git pull` from my server, following error is shown.

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://<domainname>/<user>/<repo>/': Could not resolve host: <domainname>
```

I find no reason for this error to happen.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide more information about the git command you issued and the effective URL of your server.

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't share the URL. But here is the command `sudo git pull origin phase-2`